# Are functions equivalent to built in commands in the bash / shell scripting language?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, command, function

Example

```
$ echo "This is great"
This is great
$ num2=2
$ num3="Three"
$ echo $num2
2
$ echo $num3
Three
```

Redefining echo:

```
$ echo(){ command echo "The command was redefined"; }
$ echo $num2
The command was redefined
$ echo $?
The command was redefined
```

So is this true? Are all commands in Unix shell functions and we can manipulate them like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, all Unix commands are not shell functions, but they may be overridden by a shell function.

Shell function names are not restricted by the names of built-in or external utilities. Just as you may have several external utilities with the same name under different paths, you may also have a shell function or an alias with that same name.

If there is a function called `foo` and a external or built-in utility called `foo` as well, then the function `foo` will be called.

To force the shell to pick the built-in utility, use

```
builtin foo
```

To avoid using the function `foo`, use

```
command foo
```

To guarantee that an external utility is used instead of a shell function, alias or built-in utility, use the full path to it, e.g.

```
/bin/echo
```

Aliases and functions occupy the same namespace, so you can't have an alias and a function with the same name.

---

In short:

Unix commands may be

- aliases, or
- shell functions, or
- utilities built into the shell, or
- external utilities (compiled binaries or scripts written in any scripting language).

Some "commands" are not commands but keywords, such as `for` and `if` etc. These may also be overridden by aliases and shell functions for extra exciting shell experiences (i.e. don't do that).

Answer (score 3):

No. While builtins can be accessed through the same namespace as functions, they are still separate entities and can be accessed, even when shadowed by a function, through the `builtin` builtin command (for extra fun, you can of course redefine `builtin` ☺). Note also that if you `unset -f echo` you'll have the builtin back.

Builtins are also, as the name suggests, built in and implemented (in bash's case) in C code generated from files like [echo.def](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/echo.def).